# how to add scrollbar in popup when i zoom in?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add scrollbar in the popup. I'm not able to add the scrollbar when I'm zooming in to 75% or 100%. It's working fine for fit screen, but not when I'm zooming in.

Here is my code. Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong? How to handle this case for mobile also? When I'm zoom in automatically the popup should be able to scroll in y direction.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .popup-container {

      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      max-width: 80%;
      max-height: 80%;
      overflow: auto;
      background-color: #000;
      padding: 20px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }


    .close-button {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      right: 10px;
      font-size: 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .container {
      width: 656px;
      display: block;
    }

    .content {
      padding: 51px 128px 32px 128px;
    }

    .logo {
      height: 48px;
      width: 48px;
      fill: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
    }

    .title {
      color: var(--Chalk, #F9FAFA);
      text-align: center;
      /* Headers / H2 */
      font-family: DAZN Trim;
      font-size: 32px;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 700;
      line-height: 36px;
      /* 112.5% */
    }

    .description {
      color: #FFF;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: DAZN Trim;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 120%;
      /* 19.2px */
      letter-spacing: 0.16px;
    }

    .monthly-card {
      border-radius: 8px;
      border: 2px solid var(--Core-Primer, #DDDEDF);
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04);
      backdrop-filter: blur(50px);
      height: 114px;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-resolution: 100dpi) {
      .popup-container {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 577px) {
      .popup-container {
        width: 100vw;

        height: 100vh;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }

      .content {
        padding: 175px 24px 24px 30px;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="openPopup()">Open Popup</button>

  <div id="popup" class="popup-container">
    <span class="close-button" onclick="closePopup()">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"
          d="M18.71 6.71004L17.29 5.29004L12 10.59L6.71004 5.29004L5.29004 6.71004L10.59 12L5.29004 17.29L6.71004 18.71L12 13.41L17.29 18.71L18.71 17.29L13.41 12L18.71 6.71004Z"
          fill="#F9FAFA" />
      </svg>

    </span>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="content-container">
          <div class="logo"></div>
          <h2 class="title">
            We are updating our pricing for ABZA UNLIMITED
          </h2>
          <p class="description">
            Pick now one of our best-selling annual saver plans compared to the monthly plan
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-conatiner">
          <div class="monthly-card"></div>
          <div class="monthly-card"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="terms-container">
          <p style="color: white;">
            Your new membership includes 1 stream.
            If you agree, your membership will change to 1 stream. After the minimum term of 12 months, you'll move onto
            on a
            rolling contract at 44,99€ per month. You can cancel with 30 days' notice. Terms & Conditions apply
          </p>

        </div>
        <div class="button-container">
          <button>
            PURCHASE PAID SUBSCRIPTION
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    function openPopup() {
      document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
    }

    function closePopup() {
      document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
      // Check for zoom level changes
      if (window.innerWidth >= 768 && window.innerWidth <= 1024) {
        var zoomLevel = window.innerWidth / window.screen.width;

        if (zoomLevel !== 1) {
          document.querySelector('.popup-container').style.overflow = 'auto';
        } else {
          document.querySelector('.popup-container').style.overflow = 'hidden';
        }
      } else {
        document.querySelector('.popup-container').style.overflow = 'auto';
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `.popup-container` `overflow-y` to `scroll`. The scrollbar will be always displayed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .popup-container {

      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      max-width: 80%;
      max-height: 80%;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      background-color: #000;
      padding: 20px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }


    .close-button {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      right: 10px;
      font-size: 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .container {
      width: 656px;
      display: block;
    }

    .content {
      padding: 51px 128px 32px 128px;
    }

    .logo {
      height: 48px;
      width: 48px;
      fill: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
    }

    .title {
      color: var(--Chalk, #F9FAFA);
      text-align: center;
      /* Headers / H2 */
      font-family: DAZN Trim;
      font-size: 32px;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 700;
      line-height: 36px;
      /* 112.5% */
    }

    .description {
      color: #FFF;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: DAZN Trim;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 120%;
      /* 19.2px */
      letter-spacing: 0.16px;
    }

    .monthly-card {
      border-radius: 8px;
      border: 2px solid var(--Core-Primer, #DDDEDF);
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04);
      backdrop-filter: blur(50px);
      height: 114px;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-resolution: 100dpi) {
      .popup-container {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 577px) {
      .popup-container {
        width: 100vw;

        height: 100vh;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }

      .content {
        padding: 175px 24px 24px 30px;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="openPopup()">Open Popup</button>

  <div id="popup" class="popup-container">
    <span class="close-button" onclick="closePopup()">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"
          d="M18.71 6.71004L17.29 5.29004L12 10.59L6.71004 5.29004L5.29004 6.71004L10.59 12L5.29004 17.29L6.71004 18.71L12 13.41L17.29 18.71L18.71 17.29L13.41 12L18.71 6.71004Z"
          fill="#F9FAFA" />
      </svg>

    </span>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="content-container">
          <div class="logo"></div>
          <h2 class="title">
            We are updating our pricing for ABZA UNLIMITED
          </h2>
          <p class="description">
            Pick now one of our best-selling annual saver plans compared to the monthly plan
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-conatiner">
          <div class="monthly-card"></div>
          <div class="monthly-card"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="terms-container">
          <p style="color: white;">
            Your new membership includes 1 stream.
            If you agree, your membership will change to 1 stream. After the minimum term of 12 months, you'll move onto
            on a
            rolling contract at 44,99€ per month. You can cancel with 30 days' notice. Terms & Conditions apply
          </p>

        </div>
        <div class="button-container">
          <button>
            PURCHASE PAID SUBSCRIPTION
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    function openPopup() {
      document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
    }

    function closePopup() {
      document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
      // Check for zoom level changes
      if (window.innerWidth >= 768 && window.innerWidth <= 1024) {
        var zoomLevel = window.innerWidth / window.screen.width;

        if (zoomLevel !== 1) {
          document.querySelector('.popup-container').style.overflow = 'auto';
        } else {
          document.querySelector('.popup-container').style.overflow = 'hidden';
        }
      } else {
        document.querySelector('.popup-container').style.overflow = 'auto';
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```